# Dynamic server value in powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, wmi-query

I am using below query to get the server details,

```
$intFreeSpace = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName Server1,server2 | Select-Object SystemName, deviceid, freespace, size
```

Now, instead of hard coded value I tried to supply server value from a variable like below

```
$serverlist = "server1,server2"
 $intFreeSpace = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName $serverlist  | Select-Object SystemName, deviceid, freespace, size
```

but this isn't working, any solution?

**Edit**:

ServerList = @("Server1") #Initialization with dummy value to insure that variable will be an array

```
 if($row[0] -eq "ServerList"){
                 $ServerList= $row[1]
               }
WRITE-HOST $ServerList
```

> Output: Server1,Server2

It is working fine when my column value is Server1.

Comment: If the value is coming from your database as a single string delimited by commas, you can use `($serverList -split ',')` as the argument for `-ComputerName` in `Get-WMIObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in an array, instead!  Otherwise, you make an attempt on 'one' computer called "server1,server2".

```
$serverlist = @("server1","server2")
$intFreeSpace = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName $serverlist  | Select-Object SystemName, deviceid, freespace, size
```

EDIT: Bill is right, you'll need to turn your string of servers into an array.  Since the result is comma delimited, you can `-split` on the comma.  This leaves you with an array.

```
$serverlist = $serverlist -split ','
$intFreeSpace = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName $serverlist  | Select-Object SystemName, deviceid, freespace, size
```

Comment: Actually, this value is coming from a column in database. When I print it is shown as Server1,Server2. I have edited my question

Comment: I have fixed it by doing **  $serverlist = $serverlist .replace(' ','').split(',')** I don't know why but it did fixed. You can modify your answer with this statement so that I can accept it.